# How to route traffic from a Windows docker host to Linux containers?

Tags: routing, docker-for-windows

The official docker docs [state](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers):

> Docker for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers.

Is there a workaround (outside of docker) to make this work anyway?

My setup so far is:

```
docker network create --driver bridge --subnet 192.168.1.0/24 alpine-net
docker run --rm --ip 192.168.1.5 -P -dit --name alpine1 --network alpine-net alpine ash
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your container to be visible from outside, try this with Elevated Power Shell
to forward a port to the container:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=yourip listenport=yourport connectaddress=10.0.75.1 connectport=yourport
```

You should see *localhost* without problems if your container is Linux.

However, if your container is Windows, you won't see *localhost* and you need to use the container's internal address:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" <cointainerid>
```